# Replace JS object by reference [refactor working code]

Tags: javascript, pass-by-reference, heap-memory

**tl;dr** Working code is at the bottom, can it be made more elegant.

I am building a [metalsmith](http://www.metalsmith.io/) (static site generator) plugin. Metalsmith plugins always take the form:

```
const myPlugin = options => (files, metalsmith, done) => {
  // Mutate `files` or `metalsmith` in place.
  done()
}
```

I have written my plugin in a functional (immutable) style (with [Ramda.js](http://ramdajs.com/)) and would like to completely overwrite `files` with the new value. The following is *conceptually* what I want, but won't work because it is reassigning `files` to `updated` not manipulating the `files` object on the heap.

```
const myPlugin = options => (files, metalsmith, done) => {
  const updated = { foo: "foo" }
  files = updated

  done()
}
```

I have achieved the desired functionality, with the following, but it seems inelegant.

```
const myPlugin = options => (files, metalsmith, done) => {
  const updated = { foo: "foo" }
  deleteMissingKeys(old, updated)
  Object.assign(old, updated)

  done()
}

const deleteMissingKeys = (old, updated) => {
  Object.keys(old).forEach(key => {
    if (!updated.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
      delete old[key]
    }
  })
}
```

Is there a better way to achieve these ends?

Comment: This should be asked on: https://codereview.stackexchange.com

Comment: @Andreas thanks. I'll repost it there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no super elegant way to do this in JavaScript, but this is not a bad thing. The truth is, well-written JavaScript should not need a behavior like this. There is no such thing as "pass-by-reference" in JavaScript, so it is natural that attempts like yours will be inelegant.

Shall a library need a behavior like this, instead of trying to work out a "hack" to pass-by-reference, there is a much more "javascriptonic" way to do it, which is pass around a wrapper object for the desired object:

```
// instead of trying to use a "hack" to pass-by-reference
var myObj = { /* ... */ };
function myFunc(obj) {
    // your hack here to modify obj, since
    // obj = { /* ... */ }
    // won't work, of course
}
myFunc(myObj);

// you should use a wrapper object
var myWrapper = {
    myObj: { /* ... */ }
}
function myFunc(wrapper) {
    wrapper.myObj = { /* ... */ };
}
myFunc(myWrapper);
```

I strongly suggest you reconsider why you really want to do this in the first place.

But if you insist, your solution isn't that bad, I like how you used `Object.assign()` instead of a clunky for loop to add the fields.

I should add, though, that depending on the situation you might also want to set the prototype of the object to the intended value (if for example the old object was an instanceof Date and you want to make it a plain object, you certainly need to call `Object.setPrototypeOf(old, Object.prototype)`).